# How to check if GLFW window is running?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I am creating an app using GLEW and GLFW. I want to check if my window is still running. Is there any way to do this?

```
int main(void)
{

app = new Application();
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(app->m_Window))
{
    /* Render here */
    renderer.Clear();

    app->Update();
    app->Render(&renderer, shader);
    glfwSwapBuffers(app->m_Window);

    /* Poll for and process events */
    app->HandleEvents();
}
glfwTerminate();
return 0;
}
```

After I close the opengl window, the console still runs.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you are trying to do? Usually, you'll have a renderloop in a glfw application that runs until `glfwWindowShouldClose` is true.

Comment: Yes, I added main.cpp in my code

Comment: You're missing a `glfwDestroyWindow(window);` right before `glfwTerminate`. (I assume that `->HandleEvents()` calls `glfwPollEvents()`).

Comment: Yes, It calls glfwPollEvents()

Comment: Did adding `glfwDestroyWindow` solve the problem?

Comment: No, it didn't. Again - the opengl window is closing, but the console is not.

Comment: Change your main method declaration to `#ifdef _WIN32
int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
#else
int main(int argc, const char** argv)
#endif // _WIN32
`. And then check your IDE settings, it should create desktop application and not the console.

Comment: I want the console running (for debbuging purposes).

Comment: When you say the console does not close, do you mean the loop never ends? Are you running it on debug mode on Visual Studio?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it. I had an infinite loop running in the background(checking for opengl errors). Thank you for your support!